# WPDB secure custom form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, wpdb

I'm creating a custom form to update rows in a secondary MYSQL DB, different from the one of wordpress. This form is public and every user can access it. So I've created a plugin and I'm using also wpdb to connect with the database.

How can I do this in a secure way?

I'm using sanitize_text_field() and then wpdb->update(). Is this safe or should I use esc_sql()?

If I can't use wpdb->update() because I need to have some != fields in where clauses, is it ok to use sanitize_text_field(), then wpdb->prepare() and then wpdb->query()?

Answer (score 1):

When getting user input to be stored on database, a good way to proceed is:

1. **Data validation**: validate the data according whith the data you expect. For example: HTML string, number, email, URL, any text with no HTML, ect. Never trust on user input or client-side validation. You can make here also some sanitization, but it is not substitute of data validation and it is not substitute of data scaping.
2. **SQL escape**: no explanation needed here I think. WorPress provide some functions and methods to perform this. `esc_sql` is the general function to prepare strings to be used in database queries. But is not always needed if you use wpdb class. For example, if using `$wpdb->insert` and `$wpdb->update` the data should be not scaped because it will be done for you.

If using `$wpdb->query`, the best method to scape the query is using `$wpdb->prepare` method. Additional scape methods are avalable in wpdb class; see [this of how to use `$wpdb->prepare`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) and this for [data escape before database interaction](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Database).

Answer (score 0):

An example for inserting data to WPDB securely. It's prepared method which prevents the sql injection. First create your form and then insert your data like the following structure. **Example:**

```
$insert_value_array = array(
    'input' => '',      // name of your input field
    'textarea' => '',   // field name
    'select' => '',     // field name
    'checkbox' => '',   // field name
);

$form_item = shortcode_atts( $insert_value_array, $_REQUEST );

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    global $wpdb;

    $full_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'your_table_name';

    // $wpdb->insert( $full_table_name, $form_item); // It's without prepare method

 // Safe data insertion with prepare method ( successful )
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
                "   INSERT INTO $full_table_name
                    ( column_name_1, column_name_2, column_name_3, column_name_4 )
                    VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s ) 
                ", // VALUES depends on your datatype. %s for string, %d for integer
                    $form_item
            ) );

};
```